# PostgreSQL Trigger Function Update

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, web

I have a table where column `sub` is first digit from column `id`.

```
    id   |  sub  |
---------+-------+
      21 |   2   |
      32 |   3   |
      43 |   4   |
```

I want to create a trigger that updates `sub` when `id` is changed.

Below is an example of the result I want:

```
    id   |  sub  |
---------+-------+
      21 |   2   |
      22 |   2   |
      43 |   4   |
```

In the second row, the value for `id` has changed from '32' to '22', so the `sub` must change from '3' to '2'.

Can someone please help me solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample schema based on your example:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id serial, sub int);
INSERT INTO t (sub) values (null);
INSERT INTO t (sub) values (null);
INSERT INTO t (sub) values (null);
```

You would use this function and trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION setSub() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.sub := substring(CAST(NEW.id as CHAR(6)), 1, 1);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER setSub
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON t
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE setSub();
```

Usage example:

```
test=# SELECT * FROM t;
 id | sub 
----+-----
  1 |    
  2 |    
  3 |    
(3 rows)

test=# UPDATE t SET id = 3000 WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE 1
test=# SELECT * FROM t;
  id  | sub 
------+-----
    2 |    
    3 |    
 3000 |   3
(3 rows)

test=#
```